# Image_picker camera causing app restart in Low memory device in Flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker, flutter-image-picker

When I open camera using image_picker in low memory devices, my app restarts after coming back. How to prevent it from restarting?
Issue is same in release mode too.
The device I am using is Redmi 7A with 2GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent it; destroying background activities in low-memory situations is fundamental to how Android works. Instead, as [explained in the package README](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#android), you need to implement state restoration in your application so that it doesn't affect user experience.

Comment: I read about this before but how to store the complete state when user left the app.